# Switch split screen game views in Portal 2 PTI

Tags: portal-2

In the Portal 2 Perpetual Testing Initiative (the map builder) you can test out your maps by going to the Game View. If you're building a co-op map, the Game View is automatically split screen, each controlled by one robot. How do I switch control of robots to test my map? Currently I can only control Atlas, but I need to switch over to P-body to complete the map. He's just sitting there, stuck at the beginning of the level.

I've tried using gestures, pinging, and keyboard shortcuts, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

The console command you are looking for is `swapsplit`.

To enable the console, start by going to Keyboard settings, enable the Developer Console, go into the binds menu and bind the console to a key you won't forget. (I use tilde `)

Once you've opened the console, type in `bind [KEY] swapsplit`, replacing [KEY] with the key you want to bind it to. Then hit enter.

In order to make sure this stays between game sessions (Portal 2's a bit weird with that), type in `host_writeconfig` and hit enter again.

Now, whenever you press that key, your split screen controller should swap!

*Note this was based off of memory and may not be 100% accurate.*